# D3 Force Layout where larger nodes cluster in center

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I've been tinkering with a force layout that will be used for a tag cloud and each tag is represented by a `<circle>` whose radius is proportional to the questions with that tag. My question is to determine how to make more popular tags trend toward the center of the cluster and less popular tags congregate around the edges of the tag cloud. So far my code looks like this:

```
function(err, results) {
  var nodes = results.tags;
  var width = 1020;
  var height = 800;
  var extent = d3.extent(nodes, function(tag) { return tag.questions.length; });
  var min = extent[0] || 1;
  var max = extent[1];
  var padding = 2;

  var radius = d3.scale.linear()
    .clamp(true)
    .domain(extent)
    .range([15, max * 5 / min]);

  // attempted to make gravity proportional?
  var gravity = d3.scale.pow().exponent(5)
    .domain(extent)
    .range([0, 200]);

  var minRadius = radius.range()[0];
  var maxRadius = radius.range()[1];

  var svg = d3.select('#question_force_layout').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

  var node = svg.selectAll('circle')
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'tag')
      .attr('r', function(tag) { return (tag.radius = radius(tag.questions.length)); });

  var tagForce = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(results.tags)
    .size([width, height])
    .charge(200) // seemed like an okay effect
    .gravity(function(tag) {
      return gravity(tag.questions.length);
    })
    .on('tick', tagTick)
    .start();

  function tagTick(e) {
    node
      .each(collide(.5))
      .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; });
  }

  function collide(alpha) {
    var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes);

    return function(d) {
      var r = d.radius + maxRadius + padding;
      var nx1 = d.x - r;
      var nx2 = d.x + r;
      var ny1 = d.y - r;
      var ny2 = d.y + r;

      quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
        if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {
          var x = d.x - quad.point.x;
          var y = d.y - quad.point.y;
          var l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
          var r = d.radius + quad.point.radius + padding;

          if (l < r) {
            l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
            d.x -= x *= l;
            d.y -= y *= l;
            quad.point.x += x;
            quad.point.y += y;
          }
        }

        return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
      });
    };
  }
}
```

To give you an idea of the amount of data being dealt with, there are 52 questions and 42 tags currently. Also the output usually ends up something like this:

[image]

I'd like the larger nodes to end up in the center.

Comment: Hmmm, you could have an invisible node that's fixed in the center and connected to all the other nodes. Then use `.linkDistance()` to make the distance between the center node and another node a function of the size of that node.

Comment: I like that idea.. let me try that out.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I ended up implementing a different solution that used a similar idea. Basically on tick event, I attracted the nodes based on their radii toward a certain ring around the center, specifically to the point on the ring where their angle from the center was. I'll post my answer in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility is to give the nodes something like mass and take it into account in the collision function.  Then you can switch on gravity and let them fight for position.
[This example](http://bl.ocks.org/cool-Blue/bd76db6e38915c30fc5b) gets there after a bit of a flurry.

Here is the modified collision function...

```
function Collide(nodes, padding) {
// Resolve collisions between nodes.
  var maxRadius = d3.max(nodes, function(d) {return d.radius});
  return function collide(alpha) {
    var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes);
    return function(d) {
      var r = d.radius + maxRadius + padding,
        nx1 = d.x - r,
        nx2 = d.x + r,
        ny1 = d.y - r,
        ny2 = d.y + r;
      quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
        var possible = !(x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1);
        if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d) && possible) {
          var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
            y = d.y - quad.point.y,
            l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
            r = d.radius + quad.point.radius + padding,
            m = Math.pow(quad.point.radius, 3),
            mq = Math.pow(d.radius, 3),
            mT = m + mq;
          if (l < r) {
            //move the nodes away from each other along the radial (normal) vector
            //taking relative mass into consideration, the sign is already established
            //in calculating x and y and the nodes are modelled as spheres for calculating mass
            l = (r - l) / l * alpha;
            d.x += (x *= l) * m/mT;
            d.y += (y *= l) * m/mT;
            quad.point.x -= x * mq/mT;
            quad.point.y -= y * mq/mT;
          }
        }
        return !possible;
      });
    };
  }
}
```

---

### Force Directed Graph with self sorting nodes - [*Position swapping*](http://bl.ocks.org/cool-Blue/7afd8ab920fd01779e01)

[image]

#### Features

- ***Accelerated annealing***
  The annealing calc is done every tick but, until alpha drops below 0.05, the viz is only updated every nth tick (n is currently 4).  This delivers significant reductions in the time to reach equilibrium (roughly a factor of 2).
- ***Force dynamics***
  The force dynamics are a function of alpha, with two phases.  The initial phase has zero charge, low gravity and low damping.  This is designed to maximise mixing and sorting.  The second phase has a higher gravity and a large, negative charge and much higher damping, this is designed to clean up and stabilise the presentation of the nodes.
- ***Collisions between nodes***
  Based on [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231298) example but enhanced to sort the radial position of the nodes based on size, with larger nodes closer to the center.  Every collision is used as an opportunity to correct the relative positions. If they are out of position then the radial ordinates of the colliding nodes (in polar coordinates) are swapped.  The sorting efficiency is therefore reliant on good mixing in the collisions.  In order to maximise the mixing, the nodes are all created at the same point in the center of the graph.  When the nodes are swapped, their velocities are preserved. This is done by also changing the previous points (`p.px` and `p.py`).  The mass is calculated assuming the nodes are spheres, using  r<sup>3</sup>, and the rebounds calculated according to relative "mass".

#### Extract

```
function Collide(nodes, padding) {
    // Resolve collisions between nodes.
    var maxRadius = d3.max(nodes, function(d) {
        return d.q.radius
    });
    return function collide(alpha) {
        var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes);
        return function(d) {
            var r   = d.radius + maxRadius + padding,
                nx1 = d.x - r,
                nx2 = d.x + r,
                ny1 = d.y - r,
                ny2 = d.y + r;
            quadtree.visit(function v(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
                var possible = !(x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1);
                if(quad.point && (quad.point !== d) && possible) {
                    var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
                        y = d.y - quad.point.y,
                        l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
                        r = d.radius + quad.point.radius + padding;
                    if(l < r) {
                        for(; Math.abs(l) == 0;) {
                            x = Math.round(Math.random() * r);
                            y = Math.round(Math.random() * r);
                            l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
                        }
                        ;
                        //move the nodes away from each other along the radial (normal) vector
                        //taking relative size into consideration, the sign is already established
                        //in calculating x and y
                        l = (r - l) / l * alpha;

                        // if the nodes are in the wrong radial order for there size, swap radius ordinate
                        var rel = d.radius / quad.point.radius, bigger = (rel > 1),
                            rad = d.r / quad.point.r, farther = rad > 1;
                        if(bigger && farther || !bigger && !farther) {
                            var d_r = d.r;
                            d.r = quad.point.r;
                            quad.point.r = d_r;
                            d_r = d.pr;
                            d.pr = quad.point.pr;
                            quad.point.pr = d_r;
                        }
                        // move nodes apart but preserve their velocity
                        d.x += (x *= l);
                        d.y += (y *= l);
                        d.px += x;
                        d.py += y;
                        quad.point.x -= x;
                        quad.point.y -= y;
                        quad.point.px -= x;
                        quad.point.py -= y;
                    }
                }
                return !possible;
            });
        };
    }
}
```

---

### Position swapping plus momentum : [*Position swapping + momentum*](http://bl.ocks.org/cool-Blue/ae365cfb13ad972c65f4)

This is a little bit faster but also more organic looking...

[image]

#### Additional features

- ***Collisions sort events***
  When the nodes are swapped, the velocity of the bigger node is preserved while the smaller node is accelerated.  Thus, the sorting efficiency is enhanced because the smaller nodes are flung out from the collision point.  The mass is calculated assuming the nodes are spheres, using  r<sup>3</sup>, and the rebounds calculated according to relative "mass".

  ```
  function Collide(nodes, padding) {
      // Resolve collisions between nodes.
      var maxRadius = d3.max(nodes, function(d) {
          return d.radius
      });
      return function collide(alpha) {
          var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes), hit = false;
          return function c(d) {
              var r   = d.radius + maxRadius + padding,
                  nx1 = d.x - r,
                  nx2 = d.x + r,
                  ny1 = d.y - r,
                  ny2 = d.y + r;
              quadtree.visit(function v(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
                  var possible = !(x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1);
                  if(quad.point && (quad.point !== d) && possible) {
                      var x  = d.x - quad.point.x,
                          y  = d.y - quad.point.y,
                          l  = (Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y)),
                          r  = (d.radius + quad.point.radius + padding),
                          mq = Math.pow(quad.point.radius, 3),
                          m  = Math.pow(d.radius, 3);
                      if(hit = (l < r)) {
                          for(; Math.abs(l) == 0;) {
                              x = Math.round(Math.random() * r);
                              y = Math.round(Math.random() * r);
                              l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
                          }
                          //move the nodes away from each other along the radial (normal) vector
                          //taking relative size into consideration, the sign is already established
                          //in calculating x and y
                          l = (r - l) / l * (1 + alpha);

                          // if the nodes are in the wrong radial order for there size, swap radius ordinate
                          var rel = m / mq, bigger = rel > 1,
                              rad = d.r / quad.point.r, farther = rad > 1;
                          if(bigger && farther || !bigger && !farther) {
                              var d_r = d.r;
                              d.r = quad.point.r;
                              quad.point.r = d_r;
                              d_r = d.pr;
                              d.pr = quad.point.pr;
                              quad.point.pr = d_r;
                          }
                          // move nodes apart but preserve the velocity of the biggest one
                          // and accelerate the smaller one
                          d.x += (x *= l);
                          d.y += (y *= l);
                          d.px += x * bigger || -alpha;
                          d.py += y * bigger || -alpha;
                          quad.point.x -= x;
                          quad.point.y -= y;
                          quad.point.px -= x * !bigger || -alpha;
                          quad.point.py -= y * !bigger || -alpha;
                      }
                  }
                  return !possible;
              });
          };
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: I was looking at the example, and the end result is impressive, but for aesthetic reasons I'm not very fond of the chaos before that point. It's a valid solution though, so thanks for your input.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, yes I agree, it's a bit wild and wooly. More fun than practical.  Not sure if it could be settled down by adjusting charge and friction...  I had [this one](http://bl.ocks.org/cool-Blue/f6c38a2d0648233c503e) and I just thought I'd see if it would work like that. :q

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, I got fascinated by how to let the nodes figure it out for themselves... here is [another way to do it](http://bl.ocks.org/cool-Blue/ae365cfb13ad972c65f4) just for fun

Comment: Runs very slowly on my mobile Safari so I'll take a look in the morning, though from what I can tell it looks a lot less chaotic than your first attempt. If it looks good on my computer I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback, I'll add that one to the answer. It's worth noting though that, if you take out the radial position swapping and just rely in the weighted rebound or vice versa, it still works more or less the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I added to make it work:

```
var x = width / 2;
var y = height / 2;

var ring = d3.scale.linear()
  .clamp(true)
  .domain([35, 80]) // range of radius
  .range([Math.min(x, y) - 35, 0]);
// smallest radius attracted to edge (35 -> Math.min(x, y) - 35)
// largest radius attracted toward center (80 -> 0)

function tagTick(e) {
  node
    .each(gravity(.1 * e.alpha)) // added this line
    .each(collide(.5))
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; });
}

function gravity(alpha) {
  return function(d) {
    var angle = Math.atan2(y - d.y, x - d.x); // angle from center
    var rad = ring(d.radius); // radius of ring of attraction

    // closest point on ring of attraction
    var rx = x - Math.cos(angle) * rad;
    var ry = y - Math.sin(angle) * rad;

    // move towards point
    d.x += (rx - d.x) * alpha;
    d.y += (ry - d.y) * alpha;
  };
}
```